# Difference between regression tree and autoregressive tree model

Tags: r, forecasting

I am using autoregressive tree model for forecasting but m confused between regression tree and autoregressive tree model. Are these same

Answer (score 1):

An autoregressive model is any regression model (linear or non-linear) where the inputs to the model are past values of the output variable.

For example, a regression model to predict sales for this week $S_{T}$:

$S_{T} = f(price, promotion, season)$  - here the input variables are different from the output variable.

An auto-regressive model would look more like:

$S_{T} = f(S_{T-1}, S_{T-2}, S_{T-3})$  - here the input variables are past observations of the output variable, with $S_{T-1}, S_{T-2}, S_{T-3}$ being the sales from last week, two weeks ago, and three weeks ago.

Most auto-regressive models are linear models, see [AR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_model), [ARMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive%E2%80%93moving-average_model) and [ARIMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_integrated_moving_average) models.

But they can be non liner as well. An autoregressive tree model would be non-linear.